# How to use variable as an argument for command in "Invoke-Expression"

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I'm getting the error

> Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is null.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
>       + PSComputerName        : X

when I try to use

```
$command = "cmd.exe /c $($currentLocation)/Ping.cmd"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $systemName -credential $credentials -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command: $command }
```

How do I use a variable like this? I have this as a requirement so I can't use it directly, it needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the `-ArgumentList` parameter with `Invoke-Command` or access your variable using `$using:` like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $systemName -credential $credentials -ScriptBlock {
    Invoke-Expression -Command: $using:command
}
```